# Matrix form of translation operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators

How to derive the matrix form of the [translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_(geometry)) operator? If $T_x$ is the matrix form of translation along $x$-axis and $T_y$ is along $y$-axis then what will be the translation matrix on the $xy$-plane.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say for a given Hamiltonian $\mathcal H$, you find the set of eigenstates $\left| n \right>$, lets say $n = 0,1,2 \ldots N$.

Now, if you want to find the matrix representations of some operator $\hat{\mathcal O}$ (the single-particle operators $T_x, T_y$ in your case) you want to find the matrix elements like
$$
\left<n\right|\hat{\mathcal O}|\left.m\right> = \mathcal O_{n,m}
$$
And calculate $\mathcal O_{n,m}$ for all $n = 0,1,2,\ldots,N$ and $m=0,1,2,\ldots,N$. Now, construct the matrix with this elements
$$
\mathcal O = \pmatrix{\mathcal O_{1,1}  & \ldots & \mathcal O_{1,N}\\
\vdots &\ddots & \vdots \\
\mathcal O_{N,1}& \ldots &  \mathcal O_{N,N} }_{N\times N}
$$
This is the most general way to construct a matrix representation of any single particle operator. This is how far you go without giving any explicit form of the Hamiltonian.

So, you first need to find the states and then find the matrix elements of the operator using the states.

I've taken the liberty to define a general single-particle operator $\mathcal O$. Just replace $\mathcal O$ with $T_x$ and $T_y$.

The translation operator $T_r$ is defined by it's operation on a state as
$$
T_r \left| x \right> = \left|x + r \right>
$$
So if you want to calculate the matrix element $\left<n\right|T_r|\left.m\right>$ then the calculation goes as following
$$
\left<n\right|T_r|\left.m\right> = \int dx \left<n\right|T_r
\left|x\right> \left< x\right.|\left.m\right> \\
=\int dx \left<n\right.\left|x+r\right> \left< x\right.|\left.m\right> \\
=\int dx \psi_n(x+r)^* \psi_m(x)
$$
This integral is not 0 generally (don't confuse it with orthonormality condition as the arguments of the $\psi$ are different ). You'll have to calculate this kind of integral for all the states and arrange them in the aforementioned matrix.

Comment: But when we place Tx in the middle, it will shift the eigen state on the right. so the inner product will be zero always.

Comment: @PrabhupadaDixit have a look at the updated answer